# How to throw out outliers in a pandas dataframe without iterating over rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe *data* with numerical values in columns *X* and *Y*. The procedure that I'm trying to replicate in python code is as follows:

- Assume that values in *Y* can be approximated as a function of values in *X* in the form of *Y_i = a ln(X_i) + b*, where *a* and *b* are some coefficients. Find these coefficients *a* and *b*.
- Throw out / ignore values in column *Y* which deviate from this curve more than *d* units, i.e. if some *Y_i* is such that *Y_i > a  ln(X_i) + b + d* or *Y_i < a ln(X_i) + b - d* then we ignore it.
- Approximate the remaining data with a curve of the same form again and find new coefficients *a* and *b*.

So far I have something like that

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsm")

def func(s, a, b):
    return a * np.log(s) + b

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data['X'], data['Y'])
a, b = popt
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) says that iterating over rows should be avoided when possible so what would be the right way to perform the given procedure? Can anyone show me the right code?

Comment: You can add a column to the data frame with the calculated error. You can the filter the data frame if error threshold is exceeded. Side note: with a language such as Julia, you would not have to worry about performance when iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally translate the formula into Python and then keep the rows that meet the condition:

```
mask = np.abs(a * np.log(data['X']) + b - data['Y']) < d
new_data = data[mask]
```